# what exchange properties change when a draft is resaved?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Let's say you want to synchronize drafts down from an Exchange server to a client application.  Every Update event returned from an EWS call to `SyncFolderItems` *could* be a draft edit, or it could be a change to other properties, or both.  If you only want to download message content when the draft gets edited, which Exchange properties should the client check?

`PR_ENTRYID` is constant through edits.  So are `PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME`, `PR_CREATION_TIME`, and `PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME`.  `PidNameLastSaveDateTime` and `PidNameEditTime` aren't set on draft messages.  So what (other than the content) changes only when a draft is edited?

Answer (score 0):

The best option that's been suggested to me is `PR_CHANGE_KEY`.  It changes on edit and move, but apparently not on any other attribute change.